# set-cookie header will be ignored even by enabling withCredentials option, angular + electronjs

Tags: angular, cookies, electron, session-cookies, angular-httpclient

I have a desktop application which has to send http request to other sites and get some data and response cookies:

here is my code to send and http request with `HttpClient`:

```
getSite(url: string): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    const types = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Accept', types);

    return this._http.get(
        url,
        {
            observe: 'response',
            headers: headers,
            responseType: 'text',
            withCredentials: true
        }
    );
}
```

the problem is that there is no `set-cookie` header in the response.

btw: I also disabled `webSecurity` when the application window is creating due to CORS problem

so what is the problem?